# Firestore snapshot is empty

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I need to retrieve data from a Firestore db but when I debug it, I get a message that the snapshot doesn't have any data.

I think I have the query structured correctly:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('company')
                  .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
                  .collection('trxns')
                  .get(),
```

The Firebase path should be:
company >> CTsaGabEp69DuVLwHsFM >> trxns >> j5zmc9UjAwucl3z12OZr

This is based on the following Firebase structure:
[image: Firebase structure: company >> trxn]

[image]

Do I have the query correct or why is my snapshot empty? I have data in the document.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code to this:

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('company')
                  .doc($companyId)
                  .collection('trxns')
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return isLoaded
                    ? ListView.builder(
```

and I created companyId here:

```
var companyId;

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    companyId = ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId;
    super.setState(fn);
  }
```

Now, I am getting an error on this line: .doc($companyId). It says $company is undefined and on the initial loading of the page setState function is not executed so companyId is null.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('company').doc($companyId).collection('trxns').doc($trxnsId).get()` You are missing the second `doc(id)` call.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Can't I use  ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId in place of the $companyId?  Also, I want to be able to retrieve all the documents in the trxns collection.  How would I make this work?